# Mongoose aggregate to get 2 variables

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have trouble using aggregate to get 2 variables.
In my collection, I would like to filter out certain documents by the createdAt
and push each matching document in an array variable.

After that, I would also like to have a second variable, which shows me the count of the amount of documents, which matched.

I managed to do both separate in their own aggregate, but somehow I can't combine them together to work in 1 aggregate

The one for array of objects:

```
const data = await MyList.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            createdAt: { $lt: new Date(myDate) }
        }
    },
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $skip: 20 }
]);
```

The one for count:

```
const data = await MyList.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            createdAt: { $lt: new Date(myDate) }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $skip: 20 }
]);
```

So what I would like to have in the data variable is something like this:

```
{
    items: [ {...}, {...}, ...],
    count: 24
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mongodb server version is equal to or greater then 3.4, you can use the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation:

```
const data = await MyList.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: { $lt: new Date(myDate) }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      items: [{ $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }],
      count: [
        {
          $count: "count"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

This will give you a result like this: (items will have 10 item, but the count will be total document count which matches the criteria)

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": "5dd5182d45409447308379df",
        "createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:40:21.040Z",
        "name": "a1",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5dd5183345409447308379e0",
        "createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:40:21.040Z",
        "name": "a2",
        "__v": 0
      },
      ...
      ...
      {
        "_id": "5dd5185545409447308379e8",
        "createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:40:21.040Z",
        "name": "a10",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "count": [
      {
        "count": 21
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can reshape this data like this:

```
    let result = {
      items: [],
      count: 0
    };

    if (data && data[0] && data[0].items.length) {
      result = {
        items: data[0].items,
        count: data[0].count[0].count
      };
    }
```

Which will result like this: (easier for clients to parse)

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": "5dd5182d45409447308379df",
      "createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:40:21.040Z",
      "name": "a1",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5dd5183345409447308379e0",
      "createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:40:21.040Z",
      "name": "a2",
      "__v": 0
    },
    ...
    ...
    {
      "_id": "5dd5185545409447308379e8",
      "createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:40:21.040Z",
      "name": "a10",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "count": 21
}
```

And if no document matches, the result will be:

```
{
    "items": [],
    "count": 0
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I tried it and I have 2 problems with it:
1. it counts the items even if they didn't get in the item list, for example if my array in items is empty the count still shows a number like 51 (all the items in the collection)
2. is there a way, that the data is not directly an array? for example if I want to get the count I would need to do something like data[0]total[0]total which doesn't look very pretty

Comment: @Emre yes you are right, I updated the answer, can you check?

Comment: yes, perfect, that did the trick thanks, but can we somehow fix the structure of the data? because everything is always inside an array, for example if I have no items in the array the data looks like this:

[
    {
        "items": [],
        "count": []
    }
], or is there no way around, that the data is not in an array? because it would make more sense with this kinda data to be directly in an object where I just directly can access object.items / object.count

Comment: yeah I hoped maybe for a solution, where the aggregate returns the clean data directly without me adjusting it, but I guess there is no way for it. I will adjust it after the aggregate manually like in your example, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You are welcome, I think it is not a big issue, we can shape the result easily as we want .